# How to use Chernoff bound on binomial trails

Tags: probability, probability-theory

(Not fair coin!) Head with probability $0.9$ and tail with probability $0.1$ 
use Chernoff bound for the probability of more than 70% head in $n$ trails that tested. 
I think its binomial distribution so:
$$P=\begin{cases}0.9 &X=1 \\ 0.1 & X=0 \\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}$$
and MGF is :
$$(1-p+pe^s)^n$$
but Chernoff bound Theorem says:
$$P[X\ge c] \le min \space e^{-sc} \phi_X(s)$$ something like this.

 I have searched a lot i couldn't find similar question with solution. If just anyone can give me a Right form of Chernoff bound as a hint I can handle this question thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your variables, Chernoff bound is given by
$$
P(X\geq c) \leq \min_{s>0} \mathbb{E} \left[ e^{s(X-c)}\right] = \min_{s>0} e^{-sc} \phi_X (s) = \min_{s>0} e^{-sc} (1-p+pe^s)^n
$$

The minimizing $s$ satisfies

$$
\frac{d}{ds} e^{-sc} (1-p+pe^s)^n = e^{-sc}(1-p+pe^s)^{n-1} \left[ npe^s - c(1-p+pe^s) \right] = 0
$$

Since $s>0$, the part inside the square brackets has to be zero, hence,

$$
e^s = \frac{1-p}{p\left( \frac{n}{c}-1\right)}
$$

Plugging this back in,

$$
P(X \geq c) \leq \frac{(1-p)^{n-c} \left(\frac{n}{c}\right)^n p^c}{\left(\frac{n}{c}-1\right)^{n-c}}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give me bit more hint? Like begging of progress.. Because that form is just what i wrote

Comment: Hope this helps, you just need to plug in the correct values for $c$ and $p$.

Comment: $p$ is 0.9 but not sure about $c$ its probably 70% which means $c=0.7$ ?

Comment: The $X$ in the answer refers to the sum of Bernoulli RVs (not the same $X$ in your question), and the moment-generating function is that of this X, which is binomially distributed. So you want the probability that $X$ is more than $0.7n$, which means...

Comment: and $c=0.7n$? I thought c is independent constant that usually will be given in questions. Sorry its because I have been solving inequalities with given c like $P[X\ge 3.2]$

Comment: By the way, if $p=0.9$, Chernoff bound becomes trivial if you are interested in the probability of more than 70% heads. Note that the expectation of the fraction of heads is 0.9 already. The bound in the answer is meaningful only if $c>np$.

Comment: I will take a look at this theoroms deeply later i have limited time to submit my HW this question was only part of one question, So i just put $p=0.9$ and $c=0.7n$ and solved. so was it wrong ? what should i match $p$ with? Please just tell me?